# Embedded database on openwrt router with 28mb flash and 156mb ram. 32 gb sd card supported

Tags: networking, embedded-systems, embedded-database

i am now working on a embedded project. I am looking for local data buffer storage. I am searching for some embedded databases. I need to install this database on a router with MIPS architecture and openwrt OS. I could see many embedded databases which they say could be compatible with linux, Do any one of you have any idea what is the best possible to have a local data buffer for such kind of a device.Your experiences could help me save a lot of time, so please do share here if you have any idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Sqlite, Sqlite, Sqlite